# Why are albert result items not sorted the way I prefer?

Tags: albert

I would like to move the result items of the application extension up  in front. Albert seems to have no particular order for items and actually I dont like this fact. How can I achieve something similar?

Comment: For us who don't know what "albert" is - https://github.com/albertlauncher/albert - might be a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results of the different plugins are not sorted in a special order. This is by design. Fortunately Albert remembers your usage patterns.

In detail Albert sorts by *urgency*, *score* and *length of title*, in this order. The score is determined by the score an extension gives the item and the usage score. The score of the extension is often the ratio of the match length to title length and the usage score is your usage history with a [1/(days since last usage)](https://github.com/albertlauncher/albert/blob/dev/src/app/querymanager.cpp#L234).

If you use albert a while you will get a comfortable order of the items. Just “teach” it your preferences.

<sub>Note: I am the author of this app. This Q&A is part of the migration of the FAQ to the public.</sub>